# Redirect if username and password are correct

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm building a jquery mobile app with authentication and I want to redirect the page when the username and password are right. When the authentication is right it bring out a message "correct" and I want it to redirect when the message is "correct". I have this script but it seems not to work;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form2").on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "log.asp",
            data: data
        }).success(function (data) {
            $('#new_entry').html(data);

            if (data === 'correct') {
                window.location = 'myapp.html';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What incorrect behavior is happening now? Does `log.asp` produce the response that you are looking for ('correct')? If so, does the success handler get executed?

Comment: yes it does produces 'correct' message but fails to redirect

Comment: if you do a console.log(data) what do you see?

Comment: Try using `window.location.replace('myapp.html')`

Comment: try window.parent.location.href = "myapp.html';

Comment: `window.location.assign('myapp.html')` should be cleaner than `replace()` method

Comment: It is not cleaner, they have different usage. With `assign` you load a new document whereas `replace` replaces the existing document and therefore won't be saved in session history. No need to keep history in this case.